# Replacing first occurence of character in a string using HiveQL

Tags: hive, hql, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace the first occurrence of `'-'` in a string in Hive table. I am using HiveQL. I searched this topic here and other websites, but could not find clear explanation how to use metacharacters with `regexp_replace()` to do that.

This is a string from which I need to replace first '-' with empty space: `16-001-02707` 
The result should be like this: `16001-02707`
This is the method I used:

```
select regexp_replace ('16-001-02707','[^[:digit:]]', '');
```

However, this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace ('16-001-02707','^(.*?)-', '$1');
```

> 16001-02707

---

**Following the OP question in the comments**

```
with t as (select '111-22-333333-4-555-6-7-8888-999999' as col)

select  regexp_replace (col,'^(.*?)-','$1')
       ,regexp_replace (col,'^(.*?-.*?)-','$1')
       ,regexp_replace (col,'^((.*?-){2}.*?)-','$1')
       ,regexp_replace (col,'^((.*?-){3}.*?)-','$1')
       ,regexp_replace (col,'^((.*?-){4}.*?)-','$1')
       ,regexp_replace (col,'^((.*?-){5}.*?)-','$1')

from    t
```

---

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|                _c0                 |                _c1                 |                _c2                 |                _c3                 |                _c4                 |                _c5                 |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| 11122-333333-4-555-6-7-8888-999999 | 111-22333333-4-555-6-7-8888-999999 | 111-22-3333334-555-6-7-8888-999999 | 111-22-333333-4555-6-7-8888-999999 | 111-22-333333-4-5556-7-8888-999999 | 111-22-333333-4-555-67-8888-999999 |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thank you so much! It works. I wonder what does each element mean? I tried to decipher it using the list of metacharacters, but could not get it work. In case if I need to replace second or third occurences?